# RedisBroadcaster Null on Connection

Tags: laravel-5.3, publish-subscribe

I am trying to use event broadcasting with Laravel 5.3 using redis as PUBSUB and socket.io as nodjs websocket server.

When I invoke redis publish command the event is broadcasted and processed by the websocket server

```
\Redis::publish('channel-order-1', json_encode(['event' => 1, 'data'=>2]));
```

However when I try to fire it using event helper

```
event ( new Events\OrderStatusChanged(1))
```

I get the following stack trace error

```
[2018-04-10 15:16:27] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function publish() on null in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/RedisBroadcaster.php:99 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(52): Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\RedisBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'App\\Events\\Orde...', '{"event":"App\\\\...') #1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(73): Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent->fire(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob), Array) #2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(203): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire() #3 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(153): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('beanstalkd', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\BeanstalkdJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions)) #4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(75): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runNextJob('beanstalkd', 'high,low,defaul...', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions)) #5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(100): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('beanstalkd', 'high,low,defaul...', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions)) #6 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(84): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('beanstalkd', 'high,low,defaul...') #7 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire() #8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(508): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #9 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array) #10 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(261): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #11 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #12 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(817): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #13 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #14 /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(116): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #15 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #16 /var/www/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput)) #17 {main} [] []
```

My Event is as follow

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Order;
use App\Repositories\Users\ClientRepo;
use App\ShopperDetail;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

    class OrderStatusChanged implements ShouldBroadcast
    {
        use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

        public $payload;

        public $channelSufix;

        /**
         * Create a new event instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct($orderId)
        {
            $order = Order::where('id', $orderId)->first();
            $this->channelSufix = $orders->group;
            $this->payload = $order;
        }

        /**
         * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
         *
         * @return Channel|array
         */
        public function broadcastOn()
        {
            return ['channel-order-' . $this->channelSufix];
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
when I change my queue driver to sync from beanstalkd it works. However the queue functionality is irreplaceable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is problematic to implement `ShouldBroadcast` which uses `beanstalkd` as a queue service however when I have implemented `ShouldBroadcastNow` the event is fired and listened to at the websocket server?

Why using queue with redis pubsub is creating null connection to redis?